# Bulk Insert Using Sqlalchemy and Pandas on Many to Many Relationship

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have 5 pandas DataFrames that represent tables in an existing PostgreSQL database that are linked through many to many relationships. My question is how would I go about inserting the data in these dataframes into the database.

So far, I have used `automap()` to get the sqlalchemy ORM objects, but is the best way to then loop through every dataframe row and create an ORM object for the row of data. Then after, I suppose I would have to reloop through each of the objects and use `.add()` to map the relationships between all the objects.

Is this the best way? Seems redundant and inefficient.

Comment: do you use bulk inserts?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following from pandas which has a relation with sqlalchemy:

```
df.to_sql('TABLENAME', engine, index=False, if_exists=append)
```

when creating the engine I use the option of *fast_executemany=True* which makes it a lot faster.

Here is the url for to_sql function:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html